# Laravel - Displaying fields with many to many relationship according field in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have this database structure

```
table users     table office_user    table offices
-----------     -----------------    -------------

id *            id *                 id *
full_name       user_id              name       
                office_id
                joined_at
```

So in my project every office has many users and user can be joined to many offices in date (joined_at)

User.php model

```
public function offices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Office)->withPivot('joined_at');
    }
```

Office.php model

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User)->withPivot('joined_at');
    }
```

OfficeController.php

```
public function show(Office $office)
    {
        $users = User::with(array('phones', 'offices' , function($query)
        {
            $query->orderBy('joined_at', 'desc');
        }))->get();
        return view('dashboard.offices.show', compact(['office', 'users']));
    }
```

I need two things :

1-   Get **current** users list for every office

2-  Count of **current** users in every office

I already achieve this:

```
<h3>{{ $office->name }}</h3><span>{{ $office->users->count() }}</span>
    @foreach ($office->users as $user)
        <li>{{ $user->full_name }}</li>
    @endforeach
```

But the result is not as expected it gives me all users in certain office and count of them regardless there joined date

I want the list of last joined users to this office and count of them according `joined_at` field in pivot table

Thank you and Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

> But the result is not as expected it gives me all users in certain office and count of them regardless there joined date

When you do `$office->users->count()` that is the expected behavior because you are retrieve all the associated `users` of every office at any time, so given that you returned all this users, the `count()` executed in the collection will count all of them.

Your pivot attribute is just a `timestamp`, so how would you reduce the number of users returned? users that joined the office today/in the last hour/in the last 15 min maybe?

If so, you can add constrains to your `count()` method to get the results you want.

As an example, in the following lines we are gonna constraint the associated offices that has a `joined_at` that belongs to today:

```
public function show(Office $office)
{
   $users = User::with([
        'phones',
        'offices' => function ($offices) {
            $offices->whereDate('joined_at', '>', now()->startOfDay());
        },
    ])->get();

    return view('dashboard.offices.show', compact([office, 'users']));
}
```

Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) of the documentation:

> ### Constraining Eager Loads
>
> Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship, but also specify
>   additional query conditions for the eager loading query. Here's an
>   example:
>
> ```
> $users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
>     $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
> }])->get();
> ```
>
> In this example, Eloquent will only eager load posts where the post's
>   `title` column contains the word `first`. You may call other query
>   builder methods to further customize the eager loading operation:
>
> ```
> $users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
>     $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
> }])->get();
> ```

Comment: I don't want users in a specific day .. i just want the users where belong now to the office ... for example .. if user 'jack' joined office 1 in 1/1/2019 and leave it to join to office 2 in 5/5/2019 .. and back to office 1 in 6/6/2019 .. when i list all users in office 1 i want user to displayed ones represent his current position not twice as i get now .. and the count users in office 1 is one not two as i get .. i think i have to use ```first``` but don't know how .. hope it's clear  .. thank you for your time